# Integration included with square-roots

Tags: calculus, integration

While I was deriving an CDF, I needed to solve following integral which I could not solve:

$$I_1=\int_{\sqrt{d^2-t}}^{\sqrt{d^2+t}}\sqrt{\sqrt{4 d^2 x^2+t^2}-\left(d^2+x^2\right)}\,dx;\,\,0\leq t\leq d^2$$
and 
$$I_2=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{d^2+t}}\sqrt{\sqrt{4 d^2 x^2+t^2}-\left(d^2+x^2\right)}\,dx;\,\,d^2< t.$$

Does anyone have an idea to tackle this problem? Any good approximation is also desirable.

Comment: This seems to be a real monster.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: it depends on the meaning of "real" ;))) (consider $t=0$)

Comment: @metamorphy. I was trying to mean *a true monster*

Comment: As it stands, the integrand resembles the expression for the imaginary part of the square root of a complex number, but it is purely imaginary when $x\to 0$, which makes me think there's a mistake somewhere. Context?..

Comment: I have updated the problem. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea (not a complete answer) is to use $\Im\sqrt{x+iy}=\sqrt{(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x)/2}$ for real $x,y\geqslant 0$ (and the principal branch of the square root on the left). So the substitution $x=\sqrt{d^2+t\cos\phi}$ will result in $$I_{1,2}=t\Im\int_0^{\phi_{1,2}}\sqrt\frac{d^2+te^{i\phi}/2}{d^2+t\cos\phi}\sin\phi\,d\phi$$ where $\phi_1=\pi$ and $\phi_2=\pi-\arccos(d^2/t)$. With further substitution $z=e^{\pm i\phi}$, these are transformed into contour integrals, which are elliptic ones after all. Some subtleties remain - we don't have closed contours in both cases (the residue theorem doesn't apply), and we have to be careful with cuts for the integrands, but still we have some freedom for choosing forms of the contours.